# .submit(function ()) inside my modal popup is not working, and my modal popup will send normal http post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. on my main view i got the following create link:-

```
    <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/Staff/Create" id="btnCreate">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>      
    </a>


<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have the following script:-

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            $('#myModalContent').removeData("validator");
            $('#myModalContent').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myModalContent');
            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });


});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('#myModalContent', dialog).submit(function () {

        if ($('#myModalContent').valid()) {
            $('#progress').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        //location.reload();
                        alert('www');
                    } else {

                        $('#progress').hide();
                        $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
     }
        else {
           return false;
   }
    });
}
```

Now when i click on the Create link the Create action method that will return the following partial view, which will be rendered inside a modal popup :-

```
@model SkillManagement.Models.Staff

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Staff</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GUID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GUID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GUID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsExternal, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsExternal)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsExternal)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>

        //code goes here
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

till now i have every thing working well, the Get Create action method will be called and the partial view will be rendered inside a modal popup.

but now inside my partial view if i click on "Create" button , the Post create action method will be called but not due to the javascript code . and when i check `Request.IsAjax()` inside my Post create action method, i got that it is not an ajax request which means the partial view send a normal Post http and not ajax request as defined inside the script,, can anyone advice what is wrong in my current approach ?
Thanks

Comment: You don't appear to be cancelling the default submit (`return false;` is in an `else` block which may not be called). Try `$('#myModalContent', dialog).submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ....`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but i am following exactly the same approach mentioned inside this link http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1125/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-1 and when i download the project , i find that the script will be able to send ajax request without adding  e.preventDefault(); ?? can you adivce ? why this is not working in my case?

Comment: Except that the linked code (part 2 of the article) has the `return false` at the end of the script so its always called - you have it in an `else` block so its only called when the form is invalid (so if its valid it would make an ajax call and the normal submit - `return false` which prevents the standard submit is never called)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am starting to feel that i am following a wrong example at this link http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1125/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-1 ,, as i keep facing problems,,,do you consider the approach on the link valid ? as i will be rendering a partial view that contain Html.Beginform (not ajax.beginform) then i will force the Html.Beginform to send an ajax request instead of a normal http request,, i am not sure if this approach is considered valid ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke now i added return false; to my current script but this did not solve the issue ? what do you recommend ?

Comment: `return false` (or `e.preventDefault()` as I noted above) should prevent the standard form submit, so not sure whats going on. There are a few odd things in the code (maybe not related to your issue) such as the element with  `id="myModalContent"` is a `<div>` which does not have a `.submit` event so I think  `$('#myModalContent', dialog).submit(function () { ..` should be just `$(dialog).submit(function () { ..` (assuming `dialog` is the `<form>` element). And I don't really understand why your calling `bindForm();` in the `else` block.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am not expert in javaScript, if found similar code on an online tutorial ,and then i try to modify it to work with my system.  so could you please adivce how i can modify my code to be more accurate ?

Answer (score 1):

as you can see you just pass the `#myModalContent` node to the `bindForm` function, and jQuery selector looks for

```
// will never find #myModalContent
$('#myModalContent', myModalContentDOMElement).submit(function () {
```

Instead you should do something like this

```
$('form', dialog).submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default form submit action
```

Comment: my original code was as you mentioned, but since inside my main index view i already have a search form ,, so seems my jQuery code will select the Form at my main view rahter than the form insdie the modal popup.. so i have to explicitly mentione the form id ... can you adivce ?

Comment: @johnG `$('form', dialog)` is exactly does what you said, select the form within the dialog/modalContent. This wont select the form from the index view as you said. Also, you need to prevent the default action, check my edit.

Comment: thanks for the help now i modify my script as follow:- "function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
       
        if ($('form').valid()) {" . now i will get an ajax request send to my action method unlike when i used "'#myModalContent'" selector, which what i need. However now the ($('form').valid()) will not prevent the modal popup from being submitted if it have client side validation errors ,

Comment: while if i write  if ($('#myModalContent').valid()) {" the form will not be submitted if it have client side validation errors , so can you adivce ? should i use both selectors so my final script will be  :-" bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
       
        if ($('#myModalContent').valid()) {

Comment: @johnG well, That because(as I guess) `$('form')` will return an array of selected elements where it doesn't have `valid()` method. You'll be doing something like this `if($(this).valid())`.

Comment: you are correct i chnage it to be if($(this).valid()) and now i got the form validation working + when submitting the modal popup it will send  ajax post request. so now i just want to confirm something ; is my current approach considered valid?, because as you can see from my code i am rendering an html.Beginform inside my modal popup , and usually html.beginform should send full http post request (not ajax),,, then inside the script i will force the html.beginform to send ajax post request. so can you adivce, if this is valid approach to follow ?

Comment: I'm not a `.net` developer, though this is perfectly valid approach for any language. Would you mind to mark this as the answer if really helped?

Comment: so you mean forcing a regular html.beginform to submit an ajx request, using javascript is valid approach regardless if i am uing .net or at ever ?

Comment: @johnG basically both will/should produce almost same markup I suppose, but `Ajax.BeginForm` might have it's own JavaScript bindings to modify the behavior/the way the form gets submitted, which is in fact you did in your JavaScript code. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: so you mean ajax.Beginform will generate html.beginform and add java scripts to handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your form into the page via ajax, but the form you are loading is a regular html form if you want the form itself to use ajax, I believe are looking for `@Ajax.BeginForm()`.

[msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm({objectparams})){
...
```

Comment: but i found this link which implement similat functionality http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1125/search-sort-paging-insert-update-and-delete-with-asp-net-mvc-and-bootstrap-modal-popup-part-1 .. can you adivce ?

Comment: yes i know that using Ajax.Beginform  is build to send ajax post requests, but i am trying to minimize the code as possible so instead of defining the Ajax.Beginform parameters sch as loadingelementid, updatedtargetid, etc i want to have normal html.beginform and apply the setting over a script. as this script is used to provide functionalities to a WebGrid that is used in almost every module inside my application... there is not correct & wrong of either using ajax helpers ot writting the script by my self..